# How do you know what a method's exception codes are?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firedac

I typically haven't used exceptions in the past (I disable them), but with C++Builder there are things configured to use it.  So I'll embrace it, but how do you know what the exceptions are, so you know what you want to do with it?

The old method of returning error codes or NULL or FALSE are fairly simple to know the code, because they typically document the code with the function, but I find that with exceptions there is really no information about them documented with the methods/commands.

For example, the [`TFDSQLiteSecurity.SetPassword()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.SQLite.TFDSQLiteSecurity.SetPassword) function, how do I know what any exception (return) codes are to respond to them?  I don't see them listed?

Comment: The whole point of exceptions if that you no longer handle errors at the point where you call a function. Most of the time you don't need to know what exceptions are going to be thrown. However, you can't learn about a topic as broad and significant as exception based error handling in an SO question. You need a book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless documented, the only way to know what *type* of exception is being thrown is to actually *catch* it at runtime and ask it for its type.  Or look in the library source code, if available.

The thing about exceptions is that you don't always need to know *what* they are, only to know that they are being thrown *at all*.

Most exceptions are derived from common base classes ([`Sysutils::Exception`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Exception), [`std::exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception), etc), so it is usually enough to just catch an exception by its base class, not specific derived class. You need to know the specific *type* of an exception only if you want to treat *specific* exceptions differently than others, or if you need to access exception-specific details, such as for logging purposes.

In any case, in your particular example, all FireDAC exceptions are derived from the [`EFDException`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.EFDException) class, which has an [`FDCode`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.EFDException.FDCode) property holding a FireDAC error code.  And DBMS-specific FireDAC exceptions are derived from [`EFDDBEngineException`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.EFDDBEngineException), which has several more properties describing database errors, including [`ErrorCode`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.EFDDBEngineException.ErrorCode), the failed [`SQL`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.EFDDBEngineException.SQL) and its [`Params`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.EFDDBEngineException.Params), etc.

Not all exceptions are documented on a per-method basis.  Sometimes error documentation is more centralized. For instance, see the [Handling Errors (FireDAC)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Handling_Errors_(FireDAC)) documentation for more details about FireDAC exceptions.